# sed - Back reference on match pattern does not work

Tags: regex, macos, sed, backreference

I need to find in files (xml) date in this format `2021-06-25T21:17:51Z` and replace them with this format `2021-06-25T21:17:51.001Z`

I thought about using regexp with `sed` but back references does not work.

1.xml could look like this, but I have much more fields in those files, and I got fields already correct.

```xml
<Doc>
   <PUB_DATE>2021-06-25T21:17:51Z</PUB_DATE><!-- to change -->
   <DATE_COLLECT_100>2021-06-25T21:17:51Z</DATE_COLLECT_100><!-- to change -->

   <DATE_CREATION>2021-06-25T21:17:51.001Z</DATE_CREATION><!-- keep it like this -->
</Doc>
```

Desired output is

```xml
<Doc>
   <PUB_DATE>2021-06-25T21:17:51.001Z</PUB_DATE><!-- to change -->
   <DATE_COLLECT_100>2021-06-25T21:17:51.001Z</DATE_COLLECT_100><!-- to change -->

   <DATE_CREATION>2021-06-25T21:17:51.001Z</DATE_CREATION><!-- keep it like this -->
</Doc>
```

Here is my `sed`

```sh
$ sed -Ee 's#<(PUB_DATE|DATE_COLLECT_100){1}>([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}T[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2})Z</\1>#<\1>\2.001Z</\1>#' 1.xml
```

The regexep seems to be OK in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/phApi9/1)

Here a representation of it made with [https://regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%3C%28PUB_DATE%7CDATE_COLLECT_100%29%7B1%7D%3E%28%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7DT%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%29Z%3C%5C%2F%5C1%3E)
[image: representation of the regexp]

Is back references allowed in sed when they are used in the search portion ?
Am I missing something about `sed` ?
Is there a bug ?

Sed version : well... I dont know, `sed --version` `sed -v` `man sed` doesn't give it. I'm on OSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSD or OSX sed doesn't support back-reference `\1` in regex pattern.

Your choices are `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's#<(PUB_DATE|DATE_COLLECT_100)>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})Z</\1>#<\1>\2.001Z</\1>#' 1.xml
```

Or else install `gnu sed` using `home brew` installer and then use:

```
gsed -E 's#<(PUB_DATE|DATE_COLLECT_100)>([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}T[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2})Z</\1>#<\1>\2.001Z</\1>#' 1.xml
```

Comment: oh, OK! that's why it doesn't work. Thanks, I will go for `perl` than :)

Comment: yes I know, but you were so fast I should wait a couple of minutes before I could validate the answer ^^