sed backreference matches only first character of match
On my macOS 14.6.1 sed shows some unexpected behaviour and it's surprisingly hard to find anything about it on the interwebz.
I want to replace <SomeText><SomeDigits>.<TheSameText><TheSameDigits> with just one of them, so -> <SomeText><SomeDigits>. Quite simple, right?
sed -r 's/(SomeText[0-9]+)\.\1/\1/' myfile
This doesn't do anything... what? Why?
Let's try something else:
sed -r 's/SomeText([0-9]+)\.SomeText\1/SomeText\1/'

SomeText15.SomeText15 -> SomeText155

What? It matches the whole thing but then only replaces the first character of the first capturing group? Why?
I'd try sed -r 's/SomeText([0-9]+)\b\.SomeText\1/SomeText\1/' if my version of sed supported \b.
Right now, none of this makes any sense to me. regex101.com, for example, is fine with the simple version s/(SomeText[0-9]+)\.\1/\1/. ([0-9]+) is greedy and should slurp all the numbers until ..


What's going on here? Why does s/(SomeText[0-9]+)\.\1/\1/ not work with sed? I tried this with sed on alpine, too, with the same behaviour.
Why will \1 match the group but then replace only the first character?

I must be missing something obvious here and hope to facepalm heavily in about a minute.
/edit: Thanks comments,
macOS sed supports -r for compatibility reasons.
The linked duplicate is correct - I wonder why I couldn't find it; the title is good.

Perhaps this page is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838716/sed-back-reference-on-match-pattern-does-not-work

There are many flavors of regex.  And many flavors of sed.

I can repro these on MacOS Sonoma but not explain them. I'm tempted to say you have found a bug.

The default sed on MacOS is BSD sed, but you're using an old GNU sed option, -r, to try to enable EREs while the BSD (and current GNU) sed equivalent option is -E. So, maybe that's your problem?

Also, backreferences in a regexp are defined by POSIX to work in BREs but not in EREs so that again may be a problem for your sed version+script combination?
